# Need help regarding CGI scripting with C

Tags: html, c, cgi, arm, lighttpd

I need to process some of files stored on the server side and display the list of files on a web page in a browser. My server is set-up on an arm-processor and it is mini(thttpd). And only support CGI script(with C) as far as I know.

So I am asking, whether with this current set-up, can I process file system on server side and display details(like file names) on a web page upon browser interaction by just plain CGI scripting using C??? I was unable to find convincing tutorials regarding this on CGI. And installing any other components on server will be difficult as it needs to be cross-compiled against arm-platform and the also system being embedded(low on memory). I am a total newbie to this scripting. So please forgive me if you found this post silly or stupid.

And also it would be nice if you help me find some good scripting tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my dusty old [Getting Started with CGI Programming in C](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/cgic.html). It might be difficult to find good new material on the topic these days, as most people do server-side programming with other, better tools. But things like you describe would be possible. The main concern would be security, especially if you would allow the user to delete or modify files on the server.

Comment: Ok will try it out..Thanks for the response